# Simple Python Program Got Stuck

Tags: python, http, python-2.7, connection

Yesterday I wrote a simple Python program (really simple as shown below) to validate the HTTP status responses of around 5000 URLs. The thing is the program seems getting stuck for every 400 to 500 URLs. As I'm really new to programming, I have no idea how to track the problem.

I added the "a = a + 1" piece to track how many URLs had been processed when it got stuck.

How can I find what the problem is? Thank you very much！

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and Python 2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import httplib

raw_url_list = open ('url.txt', 'r')
url_list = raw_url_list.readlines()
result_file = open('result.txt', 'w')
a = 0

for url in url_list:
    url = url.strip()[23:]
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.123456789.cn')
    conn.request('HEAD', url)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    result_file.write('http://www.123456789.cn%s, %s, %s \n' % (url, res.status, res.reason))
    a = a + 1
    print a

raw_url_list.close()
result_file.close()
```

Comment: How do you know that it's "getting stuck"?

Comment: Hi Ignacio, I saw the terminal got stuck and stopped printing the numbers for a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close your connections after you are done. Just add this to the end of your for loop.

```
     conn.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! By the way, is there anything I can use to spot the problem myself, like a common way for programmers to figure out who is the culprit that causes a program to get stuck?

Comment: @BananaOnTheWall: Usually if a program slows down it means a memory leak of some kind. If you monitored the memory usage of the program, you would have noticed it start to rise. But as for a tool, well, I don't know of a way per say, aside from experience.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, your answer saves me a lot of time and I appreciate it :)